# md-slider stop anywhere without jumping to a step

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using the [md-slider directive](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSlider) and I have it set up like this:

```
<md-slider class="md-primary" ng-model="question.sliderPosition" ng-change="handleProducts()" md-discrete step="3" min="3" max="9" aria-label="rating"></md-slider>
```

There are only 3 positions. But my client doesn't want it to jump to the next position, rather they want it to stop when the user let's go of the mouse and then for my code to work out which step the point is closest to.
Does anyone know if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No the API does not expose this as an option.

However most things are possible, if you take a look at the directive's source code and commented out any references to `clamp` then it would not do as the function suggests, clamp the position of the slider to it's closest position.

When it sets the sliders percentage, e.g. when you release the mouse, it calls `clamp` and adjusts the position based on the `value` (current position) passed in.

https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/slider/slider.js#L559